# Error: Cannot find module node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new at ionic framework while trying to build the app using "ionic serve" I am facing error:
Cannot find module  node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts

> Error

```
    $ ionic serve
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mehroz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\ionic-angular\app-scripts.js:9:16)    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Mehroz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:107:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)


    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\Mehroz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:103:16)
    at Object.importAppScripts (C:\Users\Mehroz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\ionic-angular\app-scripts.js:7:20)
```

This is my ionic info

> Ionic Info

```
    $ ionic info
[ERROR] Error with .\node_modules\ionic-angular\package.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND
[ERROR] Error with .\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\package.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND

cli packages: (C:\Users\Mehroz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : not installed
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework    : not installed

System:

    Node : v8.11.2
    npm  : 6.1.0
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

> After running npm install into my project

```
$ npm cache clean --force
```

npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

```
Mehroz@DESKTOP-6L29EKQ MINGW64 /e/myapp_dwai/myapp_dwai_ap
$ npm i
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\color-convert-6ff97655\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\color-convert-6ff97655\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\color-convert-6ff97655\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\color-convert-6ff97655\conversions.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\plist-73d7a262\examples\browser\index.html'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\elementtree-e83b5bf3\tests\data\xml1.xml'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\elementtree-e83b5bf3\tests\data\xml2.xml'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\tr_global\node_modules\x'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\express\node_modules\depd\lib'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\express\node_modules'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-common-8a5036c8\src\CordovaError\CordovaError.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-common-8a5036c8\src\CordovaError\CordovaExternalToolErrorContext.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\tr_once\main.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\express\node_modules'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-android-d5c98122\bin\templates\project\res\mipmap-xhdpi\icon.png'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\test\packages\npm-test-optional-deps\test.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\attempt.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\iteratee.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\matches.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\matchesProperty.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\method.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\identity.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\mixin.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\noop.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\property.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\propertyOf.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-app-hello-world-85cc26ee\template_src\res\icon'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\range.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\constant.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-app-hello-world-85cc26ee\template_src'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\times.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\callback.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\uniqueId.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\lodash-773f12e1\utility\methodOf.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\co\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\co\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\co\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\co\History.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\co\Readme.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\acosh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\fscale.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\hypot.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\iaddh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\imul.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\fround.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\isubh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\log10.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\log1p.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\log2.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\expm1.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\rad-per-deg.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\degrees.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\radians.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\deg-per-rad.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\scale.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\cosh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\sign.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\clz32.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\signbit.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\clamp.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\sinh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\cbrt.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\tanh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\atanh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\trunc.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\asinh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\umulh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\core-js-556cdf2c\fn\math\imulh.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\ionic-angular-6b4598b4\es2015\components\thumbnail'
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: ansi-styles@2.2.0
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\chownr\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\chownr\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\chownr\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\chownr\chownr.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\strip-ansi\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\strip-ansi\license'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\strip-ansi\readme.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\chalk\node_modules'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\dezalgo\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\dezalgo\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\dezalgo\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\dezalgo\dezalgo.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\dezalgo\.travis.yml'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\concat-map\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\concat-map\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\concat-map\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\concat-map\.travis.yml'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-664eb46c\node_modules\concat-map\README.markdown'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\field\miss.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\field\object.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\field\string.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\field\sub.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\maxlisteners\main.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules\init-package-json\node_modules\promzard\example'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\npm-ae6b0b6e\node_modules'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\express\node_modules\accepts\node_modules'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\bundle_external\boop.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\bundle_external\main.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\browserify-58497d2f\test\bundle_external\robot.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\express\node_modules\send'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\myapp_dwai\myapp_dwai_ap\node_modules\.staging\cordova-browser-d41cc42c\node_modules\cordova-serve'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mehroz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-27T07_25_21_804Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try running `npm i` in your project folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install -g ionic` doesn't install to your project node folder. It is to install your cli globally. This seems already installed according to your `ionic info` output.

You have to run `npm install` command in your project folder which installs the dependencies set in package.json

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qcGZUtHSUEDqxBtbd4PxDVZcMQOEjV_r?usp=sharing

Comment: facing this issue when i run    " npm install  "    see  image  named   npm_issue

Comment: Avoid images.. try to paste as text. Also try `npm cache clean --force` and then try `npm i`.

Answer (score -1):

Note: Try to install nodemodules once again by deleting old node modules and
Make sure you are running "ionic serve" where source files exist

command

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Comment: This installs the ionic-cli globally.. Nothing to do with project node modules

Comment: i have installed ionic cli globally Sir